# DNS record does not point to the public address 10.11.12.252

Tags: iis-7

I'm a bit stuck trying to setup a second site with IIS7.

I have a site setup already that uses an SSL certificate portal.domain.com.

I want to setup a second site that utilizes that same SSL certificate for 443 as turkey.domain.com.

I have setup the server for 2 lans, portal being at 254 and turkey needs to be at 252.

I have created a new forward lookup zone and added an A host for 252.

When I try to setup the new site, I need to change the DNS record for turkey to 252 but I'm confused at this point because the A host is set to 252.

I'm not sure if anybody needs more details, ask and I can provide.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Added a second inetput folder and pointed the host headers to that... now able to host two sub sites on the same port.